# AWS dynamo DB item write issue

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I am connecting to AWS dynamodb using DAX service. While querying data from the DAX I face no issues and I am able to get the data. But when I try to insert new Items to DynameDB using DAX I am getting below error.

```
An error occurred(Unknown) when calling the defineAttributeListId operation: Client does not have permission to invoke DefineAttributeListId.
```

**Code:**

```
import amazondax


def put_movie(title, year, plot, rating):
    with amazondax.AmazonDaxClient.resource(endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000") as dax
        table = dynamodb.Table('Movies')
        response = table.put_item(
           Item={
                'year': year,
                'title': title,
                'info': {
                    'plot': plot,
                    'rating': rating
                }
            }
        )
        return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    movie_resp = put_movie("The Big New Movie", 2015,
                           "Nothing happens at all.", 0)
```

Comment: `DefineAttributeListId` looks like code that you own. Can you paste the code?